# Microsoft Azure DevOps Column Board mismatch with System.State

Tags: azure-devops

Since 17th of October, without any configuration change at our side
in our production Kanban Board, Board Column is now filled with System.State and Board Lane is now empty

We have a Board with columns: BackLog, analizzato, ToDo, Doing, Blocked, Testing, Ready For Deploy, Done

Our pBI status are: New, Approved, Committed, Ready for Deploy, Testing, Done, Removed

Column Board and pBI status are associated this way: Backlog=New, analizzato=New, ToDo=Approved, Doing=Committed, Blocked=Committed, Testing=Testing, Done=Done

by querying for board column with state returned instead and Board Lane empty, our board stiles are not working correctly (due to query value returned), plus we have problems with reporting (i.e. query all pBI in blocked column is not possible since Committed value is returned instead of Blocked)

looking around forum I have found something related to AreaPath and Team association. Our Kanban area path is a subcategory of the original Insoore (our company name) path, with associated only one team

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Hi, could you share a screenshot/gif of the querying for board column with state to help others to better understand this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test board I have replicated where the behavior is correct (as you can see here work items are mapped with correct column and swimlane):
[test board working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIywV.png)

pBI that has status Committed correctly showing Blocked Column and swimlane:
[pBI in swimlane and blocked column in Committed Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz4Ag.png)

Here is my production Board with the issues posted:
[production board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ps2W.png)

Here is the result of the query for work Item in Blocked Column:
[query in blocked column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyNVJ.png)

Due to the issue mentioned the column the System.state is taken into consideration instead of Column and since only bug have blocked status but not pBI (pBI are mapped with Committed state) only bug are returned by the query.
Blocked column has 15 work items (2 bugs and 13 pBIs):
[query blocked column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOJn6.png)

finally. if can help, here is my area path configuration (mapped with teams):
[area map configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzzEK.png)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at this  [pBI in swimlane and blocked column in Committed Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz4Ag.png), your pBI is in `ABraccini2` Area path, but when you [query blcoked column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOJn6.png), you set Area Path to `Whoosnap Insurance\Kanban`. It looks like the area path doesn't match. Please change the query filters (set Area Path to `ABraccini2`) and see if the pBIs are returned.

Here is my test sample:
[image]

Hope it can help.

Comment: ABraccini2 area path is the replicated board, 
Kanban area path is in the production board, no mismatch from this side looking the screenshot in the correct order. The error remains in production board. Thank you

Comment: sorry for confusing the replicated board and production board. Could i confirm the 13 pBIs(not returned by the query) are under `Whoosnap Insurance\kanban` Area Path?